# Rails url_for from string with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a site-local tinyurl I'm trying to make, so I need to show the full path of a URL that doesn't correspond to a controller action, and this doesn't work:

```
url_for("tiny/#{identifier}", :only_path => false)
```

because the `url_for` that takes a string doesn't then take any parameters.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit as per comment:

config/routes.rb:

```
get 'tiny/:id' => "original_controller#show", :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}
get 'tiny/:name' => "original_controller#by_name"
```

rake:

```
GET    /tiny/:id(.:format)                        original_controller#show {:id=>/\d+/}
GET    /tiny/:name(.:format)                      original_controller#by_name
```

Comment: What do your routes for 'tiny' look like? Can you do `rake routes` and  show us the relevant entries?

Comment: Added, but AFAIK, the issue is with the helper and the routes are just fine.